# How to configure Apache2 to enable error_log files per virtualHost using mod_wsgi?

Tags: python, apache2, mod-wsgi, web.py

I have multiple sites which are written in Python using web.py framework. I want to generate separate access logs and error logs files per site, i have enabled on Apache2.

How to achieve this ?
Please help me...any sort of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need write something like this

```
<VirtualHost *>
....
LogLevel debug
ErrorLog /var/log/apache/mysite/error__log.txt
CustomLog /var/log/apache/mysite/custom_log.txt combined
....
</VirtualHost>
```

The specified path must exist

I think links will be usefull

[apache settings](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html#virtualhosts)

[wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Apache_Error_Log_Files)